# connecting to my aws iot using mqtt

Tags: vb.net

I'm tring to connect my windows program to my aws mqtt using TLSv1.2.
Using a build in third part utilities , it works, with the same certificate i use in my module. So i knows that the cert process has gone ok.

In my program, when it arrives to the "client.connect" , it gives me SSPI error.

"AuthenticationException: A call to SSPI failed, see inner exception."

Can you help me ?
Am i missing something ?

Thanks a lot

```
 Dim Endpoint As String = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx.iot.us-west-2.amazonaws.com"
    Dim BrokerPort As Integer = 8883


    Dim Client As MqttClient


    Dim clientCert As X509Certificate
    Dim cacert As X509Certificate


    clientCert = X509Certificate.CreateFromCertFile("D:\Package\Optoteam.cert.pem")
    cacert = X509Certificate.CreateFromSignedFile("D:\Package\root-CA.crt")


    Client = New MqttClient(Endpoint, 8883, True, cacert, clientCert, MqttSslProtocols.TLSv1_2)

    Dim connesso As Byte = Client.Connect("Pippo")

    If (Client.IsConnected) Then

        Client.Subscribe(New String() {"Domotica"}, New Byte() {MqttMsgBase.QOS_LEVEL_AT_MOST_ONCE})
        Client.Publish("Domotica", Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("Prova"))

    End If
```

Comment: What is the inner exception?  Perhaps if you set a breakpoint at the appropriate spot and queried the connection it would shed some light on what exactly the error is.

Comment: "An unknown error occurred while processing the certificate"

Comment: "A call to SSPI failed, see inner exception."

Comment: Ah, one of those "not very helpful" inner exceptions.  It would seem that the process is having difficulty reading and processing the cert itself, it's not even getting to the endpoint.  Not to ask the obvious, but are you sure the path is right and the cert hasn't become corrupt is some way?

Comment: Amazon troubleshooting info:  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/ats-certs.html

Comment: Hi Prescott, thanks for the reply.Yes i'm sure. It doesn't say...file not found…..

Comment: I am sure i have understood why… but i don't know how to solve it.

Comment: I should pass a CERTIFICATE and not a request. The file i pass is a request and notepad modified. A certificate is not modified. Surely i should do something with that kind of file. The problem is that AWS iot wizard gives me 4 files. The request and the 2 keys...

Comment: The .Pem file is a request….while he expect a "real" certificate. Any ideas of how to generate a crt file from the 2 keys private and public ?

Comment: You would submit the request to a certificate issuing authority like Comodo.com or some other cert issuing authority.  I know you can generate such cert yourself, but I've never done it ....